# A scrollbar showing within DIV. What CSS is causing this?

Tags: css

On this webpage I've built a scrollbar seems to be appearing within the #content DIV and I can't seem to figure out why.

Link to page: http://dev.textcube.ch/oneandonly/index.php/hunde/nuri/ (username: textcube / password: textcube3600)

The CSS for #content doesn't have any set height that may be causing this nor is overflow: scroll;.

```
#content {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 100%;
width: 400px;
margin: 0px;
background: url(../images/content-bg.png) no-repeat;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 100px;
float: left;
padding: 80px 50px 0px 50px;
}
```

Any ideas on what is causing this? Ideally I'd like to know how to remove this scroll bar and have the content go all the way down the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS is causing it. Since the content is longer than `270px` a scrollbar appears.

```
<style type="text/css"> 
#blockStyle404MainArea9 {
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  max-height: 270px;
  over-flow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
} 
</style>
```

Comment: What's the path to the stylesheet that you are finding that in? I think my CMS is forcing this CSS through?

Comment: you can override the style, just add a style="max-height:2000px" to the div element if you want it to expand.